# How to run background execution forever on iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, background-process

I want to run my own task which is a timer thread in backgroud mode. I really want users can't make change or make cheat time in my app.

I have searched very much but couldn't find a reliability solution.

Anyone suggest me?

Comment: You can use online time server to get real time on app startup. This can't protect you from offline cheat.

Comment: @AndrewRomanov I know that. But my app used in offline mode very much.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot do what you want to do.  There is no way to run a background task on the iOS that is always running.  Doing so would be very energy efficient and would waste battery life.  As a result, Apple keeps tight control over when and how applications can run background tasks and they WILL schedule your work against other applications and how much power you are using.

Comment: Thank you, Scott. May I prevent, or reduce time cheat in my app? Give me a advice.

Comment: No, you can not.  What exactly are you trying to do in the background?  Is it one of the tasks listed under "Implementing Long-Running Tasks" at https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html ?

Comment: Read the document I referenced under the heading of "Implementing Long-Running Tasks" and note that VOIP applications, like Skype and Viber, are a category of applications that can request special permission to run in the background as a long running task.